# CharacterController is not moving correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im starting a new proyect in Unity and I want my character to jump and move at the same time but the codes don't work well together. the character finds it difficult to move. both work perfectly separately

this is the code im using to move around:

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour  
{  
    public float speed = 30f;              
    public float turnSpeed = 80f;  
    
    private float horizontalInput;          
    private float verticalInput;
    
    
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");   //teclas
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
        transform.Translate(speed*Time.deltaTime*Vector3.forward*verticalInput);    //movimiento
        transform.Rotate(turnSpeed*Time.deltaTime*Vector3.up*horizontalInput);      //rotar
    }
}
```

and this one is a tutorial i found for jumping:

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;   
  
public class JumpControl : MonoBehaviour  
{  
    private CharacterController controller;  
    private float verticalVelocity;  
    private float gravity = 14.0f;  
    private float jumpForce = 10.0f;  
    
    void Start()  
    {  
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();  
    }  
  
    private void Update(){  
        if (controller.isGrounded)  
        {  
            verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;  
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  
            {  
                verticalVelocity = jumpForce;  
            }  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;  
        }  
  
        Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(0, verticalVelocity, 0);  
        controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/_QajrabyTJc). Personally it's my favourite.

Comment: The title could use some work. If the title is used more effectively you could grab the attention of the right people.

Answer (score 2):

The [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) is **physics-based**. You never want to mix a physics-based movement with applying transformations via the `Transform` component. This breaks the physics, collision detection and causes all kind of unexpected behaviour and strange looking movements.

So instead of

```
transform.Translate(speed*Time.deltaTime*Vector3.forward*verticalInput);
```

you would rather want to do

```
[SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!controller) controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");   //teclas
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    transform.Rotate(turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.up * horizontalInput);

    controller.Move(speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.forward * verticalInput);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code
transform.Translate(speed*Time.deltaTime*Vector3.forward*verticalInput);
prevents the jump action.

So you can replace it with
rb.AddForce(new Vector3(horizontalInput , o, verticalInput) * speed);